# outputting values from database into html table PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have the code below which grabs data from a table based on what week the user has chosen, there are only 2 possible weeks to choose from.

It puts the title of the recipe into the relevant table based on the if statement but seems to be producing weird output.

When ever i try to view a week which only has part data filled in it bunches of the data onto the wrong cells; look in this image:
[image: Table problem]
'Salad' located on the top row should be in 'Sunday'

This only happens when the table is incomplete.

```
 if(!empty($_POST['selectweek'])) {
                        $selectweek = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['selectweek']);

                        function ouptutMeal($selectweek, $mealtime, $mealname) {
                            $sqlmeasurement2 = mysql_query("SELECT title, dayid
                                                            FROM recipe
                                                            JOIN menu ON recipe.recipeid = menu.recipeid
                                                            WHERE menu.weekid = '$selectweek'
                                                            AND menu.mealtimeid = '$mealtime'
                                                            ORDER BY dayid");

                            echo "<br/>
                                <table>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td><strong>Monday</strong></td>
                                    <td><strong>Tuesday</strong></td>
                                    <td><strong>Wednesday</strong></td>
                                    <td><strong>Thursday</strong></td>
                                    <td><strong>Friday</strong></td>
                                    <td><strong>Saturday</strong></td>
                                    <td><strong>Sunday</strong></td>
                                <tr>
                                   <td><strong>$mealname</strong></td>";
                                while($info2 = mysql_fetch_array( $sqlmeasurement2 )) {
                                    if($info2['dayid'] == '1') {
                                        echo '
                                              <td>', $info2['title'], '</td>';
                                    }

                                    elseif($info2['dayid'] == '2') {
                                        echo '
                                              <td>', $info2['title'], '</td>';
                                    }

                                     elseif($info2['dayid'] == '3') {
                                        echo '
                                              <td>', $info2['title'], '</td>';
                                    }

                                    elseif($info2['dayid'] == '4') {
                                        echo '
                                              <td>', $info2['title'], '</td>';
                                    }

                                    elseif($info2['dayid'] == '5') {
                                        echo '
                                              <td>', $info2['title'], '</td>';
                                    }

                                    elseif($info2['dayid'] == '6') {
                                        echo '
                                              <td>', $info2['title'], '</td>';
                                    }

                                    else {
                                        echo '
                                              <td>', $info2['title'], '</td>';
                                    }
                                } 
                            echo '</tr>
                                </table>';
                            }
                        ouptutMeal($selectweek, 1, 'Breakfast');
                        ouptutMeal($selectweek, 2, 'Lunch');
                        ouptutMeal($selectweek, 3, 'Evening Meal');
                        ouptutMeal($selectweek, 4, 'Pudding');
                        ouptutMeal($selectweek, 5, 'Supper & Snacks');
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do an if statement to see if a value exists if not then

```
   <td>& nbsp;</td>
```

so it fills your table correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could also declare the variables as empty before the query is run, example:

```
if(!empty($_POST['selectweek'])) {
    $info1 = '';
    $info2 = '';
    $selectweek = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['selectweek']);

    function ouptutMeal($selectweek, $mealtime, $mealname) {
        $sqlmeasurement2 = mysql_query("SELECT title, dayid
                                        FROM recipe
                                        JOIN menu ON recipe.recipeid = menu.recipeid
                                        WHERE menu.weekid = '$selectweek'
                                        AND menu.mealtimeid = '$mealtime'
                                        ORDER BY dayid");

        echo "<br/>
            <table>
                <td></td>
                <td><strong>Monday</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Tuesday</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Wednesday</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Thursday</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Friday</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Saturday</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Sunday</strong></td>
            <tr>
               <td><strong>$mealname</strong></td>";
            while($info2 = mysql_fetch_array( $sqlmeasurement2 )) {
                if($info2['dayid'] == '1') {
                    echo '
                          <td>', $info2['title'], '</td>';
                }

                elseif($info2['dayid'] == '2') {
                    echo '
                          <td>', $info2['title'], '</td>';
                }

                 elseif($info2['dayid'] == '3') {
                    echo '
                          <td>', $info2['title'], '</td>';
                }

                elseif($info2['dayid'] == '4') {
                    echo '
                          <td>', $info2['title'], '</td>';
                }

                elseif($info2['dayid'] == '5') {
                    echo '
                          <td>', $info2['title'], '</td>';
                }

                elseif($info2['dayid'] == '6') {
                    echo '
                          <td>', $info2['title'], '</td>';
                }

                else {
                    echo '
                          <td>', $info2['title'], '</td>';
                }
            } 
        echo '</tr>
            </table>';
    }
    ouptutMeal($selectweek, 1, 'Breakfast');
    ouptutMeal($selectweek, 2, 'Lunch');
    ouptutMeal($selectweek, 3, 'Evening Meal');
    ouptutMeal($selectweek, 4, 'Pudding');
    ouptutMeal($selectweek, 5, 'Supper & Snacks');
}
```