# PHP create HTML table from database

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [outputting values from database into html table PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356968/outputting-values-from-database-into-html-table-php)

I am trying to create a table in my .php document which is populated with values from a table in a database. but i cannot get it to work.

Firstly it is not deleting values when there are more than 1 row (There can only ever be 1 item on that particular day)

Secondly if there is no data for a particular day it just puts it into the cell before it, meaning it is on the wrong day.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST['recipe'])) {
        $week = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['week']);
        $day = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['day']);
        $mealtime = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mealtime']);
        $recipe = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['recipe']);

        $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE dayid = '".$day."' AND mealtimeid = '".$mealtime."'");

        if(mysql_num_rows($check) == 1) {
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM menu WHERE mealtimeid = '".$mealtime."' AND dayid = '".$day."'");
            $success = mysql_query("INSERT INTO menu (weekid, dayid, mealtimeid, recipeid) 
                                    VALUES('".$week."', '".$day."', '".$mealtime."', '".$recipe."')");

            if($success) {
                echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
                echo "<p>Your recipe was successfully added.</p>";
            }
            else {
                echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
                echo "<p>Sorry there was a problem, please try again.</p>";
            }
        }

        else {
            $success = mysql_query("INSERT INTO menu (weekid, dayid, mealtimeid, recipeid) VALUES('".$week."', '".$day."', '".$mealtime."', '".$recipe."')");

            if($success) {
                echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
                echo "<p>Your recipe was successfully added.</p>";
            }

            else {
                echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
                echo "<p>Sorry there was a problem, please try again.</p>";
            }
        }
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['selectweek'])) {
        $selectweek = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['selectweek']);

        function ouptutMeal($selectweek, $mealtime, $mealname) {
            $sqlmeasurement2 = mysql_query("SELECT title, dayid
                                            FROM recipe
                                            JOIN menu ON recipe.recipeid = menu.recipeid
                                            WHERE menu.weekid = '$selectweek'
                                            AND menu.mealtimeid = '$mealtime'
                                            ORDER BY dayid");

            echo "<br/>
                <table>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><strong>Monday</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Tuesday</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Wednesday</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Thursday</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Friday</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Saturday</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Sunday</strong></td>
                <tr>
                   <td><strong>$mealname</strong></td>";
                while($info2 = mysql_fetch_array( $sqlmeasurement2 )) {
                    if(empty($info2['dayid'])) {
                        echo '<td></td>';
                    }
                    elseif($info2['dayid'] == '1') {
                        echo '
                              <td>', $info2['title'], '</td>';
                    }

                    elseif($info2['dayid'] == '2') {
                        echo '
                              <td>', $info2['title'], '</td>';
                    }

                     elseif($info2['dayid'] == '3') {
                        echo '
                              <td>', $info2['title'], '</td>';
                    }

                    elseif($info2['dayid'] == '4') {
                        echo '
                              <td>', $info2['title'], '</td>';
                    }

                    elseif($info2['dayid'] == '5') {
                        echo '
                              <td>', $info2['title'], '</td>';
                    }

                    elseif($info2['dayid'] == '6') {
                        echo '
                              <td>', $info2['title'], '</td>';
                    }

                    else {
                        echo '
                              <td>', $info2['title'], '</td>';
                    }
                } 
            echo '</tr>
                </table>';
            }
        ouptutMeal($selectweek, 1, 'Breakfast');
        ouptutMeal($selectweek, 2, 'Lunch');
        ouptutMeal($selectweek, 3, 'Evening Meal');
        ouptutMeal($selectweek, 4, 'Pudding');
        ouptutMeal($selectweek, 5, 'Supper & Snacks');
        }
    }

    else {
?>
```

This is the form it gets the data from:

```
<form method="post"
      action="">
  <fieldset>
    <label for="week">Select Week:</label> <select name="week">
      <option value="0">
        Select Week<?php echo $item; ?>
      </option>
    </select> <label for="day">Select Day:</label> <select name=
    "day">
      <option value="0">
        Select Day<?php echo $item2; ?>
      </option>
    </select><br />
    <br />
    <label for="mealtime">Select Meal Time:</label> <select name=
    "mealtime">
      <option value="0">
        Select Meal Time<?php echo $item3; ?>
      </option>
    </select><br />
    <br />
    <label for="recipe">Select Recipe:</label> <select name="recipe">
      <option value="0">
        Select Recipe<?php echo $item4; ?>
      </option>
    </select> <input type="submit"
              id="login-submit"
              value="Add to Menu" />
  </fieldset>
</form>

<form method="post"
      action="">
  <label for="selectweek">Select Week:</label> <select name=
  "selectweek">
    <option value="0">
      Select Week<?php echo $item; ?>
    </option>
  </select> <input type="submit"
        id="login-submit"
        value="View Menu" />
</form>
```

[image: Example] -- The item on the end is meant to be on Sunday but is behind because a previous day does not have a item. How would i make that item go to Sunday, while keeping a gap where the other item isn't.

Comment: What is the point of the if statement ? the output is always the same ? `echo '<td>', $info2['title'], '</td>';`

Comment: if(mysql_num_rows($check) == 1) this must be like if(mysql_num_rows($check) > 0) this doesnot solve the problem offcourse. but cause issue

Comment: Please don't repost your questions. If you want to add further details, edit the original question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use if to check if value is empty or not. Some thing like this.

```
if($info2['dayid'] == "") {
      echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
   }
```

it will fill it properly, without disturbing it layout.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried putting that if statement at the front of the others, but the result is still the same.

Comment: try it while you are printing it in your table..

Comment: oh, where did you put the above if statement? Inside or outside the while loop?